# button click of header not working in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

In javascript i have following code
   $(document).ready(function() {

```
            var someObj = [];
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        someObj.push($(this).attr("name"));
                    }
                    console.log(someObj);
                })
            });
            $("#selectAll").click(function() {
                $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
            }
            );
            $("#btn1").on("click", function() {
alert("refresh clicked");
});
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "sDom": '<"top"<"#refresh">ip>rt<"clear">',
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "bPaginate"
                        : true,
                "bFilter"
                        : true,
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0]}
                ],
                /*"aoColumns": [
                    {type:"hidden"},
                    {type: "select", values: ['All', 'Red Cross', 'Save The Bay']},
                    {type: "select", values: ['All', 'Humanitarian', 'Educational', 'Environmental']},
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    {type: "select", values: ['All', 'Approved', 'Pending', 'Rejected']}
                ],*/    
                "bInfo"
                        : true,
                "bAutoWidth"
                        : true}).
                    columnFilter();
            $("#refresh").html('<input type="button" value="reject" id="btn1" />');
            function fnCreateSelect(aData)
            {
                var r = '<select><option value=""></option>', i, iLen = aData.length;
                for (i = 0; i < iLen; i++)
                {
                    r += '<option value="' + aData[i] + '">' + aData[i] + '</option>';
                }
                return r + '</select>';
            }
            new FixedHeader(oTable, {"top": true});
        });
</script>
```

In html i have following code.

```
  <table  id="example"  class="display">
        <thead>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"></th>
        <th>Organization Name</th>
        <th>Type Of Event</th>
        <th>Date Range</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>No of Hours</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Organization Name</th>
            <th>Type Of Event</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>

        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check1"></td>
            <td class="read_only">Save The Bay</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check2"></td>
            <td>Red Cross</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check3"></td>
            <td class="read_only">Save The Bay</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="check4"></td>
            <td>Red Cross</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="check5"></td>
            <td class="read_only">Save The Bay</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="check6"></td>
            <td>Red Cross</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="check7"></td>
            <td class="read_only">Save The Bay</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="check8"></td>
            <td>Red Cross</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="9" name="check9"></td>
            <td class="read_only">Save The Bay</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="10" name="check10"></td>
            <td>Red Cross</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="11" name="check11"></td>
            <td class="read_only">Save The Bay</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="check12"></td>
            <td>Red Cross</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="13" name="check13"></td>
            <td class="read_only">Save The Bay</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="14" name="check14"></td>
            <td>Red Cross</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="15" name="check15"></td>
            <td class="read_only">Save The Bay</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="16" name="check16"></td>
            <td>Red Cross</td>
            <td>Educational</td>
            <td>2012-09-01</td>
            <td class="center">Abc</td>
            <td class="center">23</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>action</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
```

What i am trying to do is create div named refresh dynamically at initialization time and then add button to that div but click of that button is not working.

Comment: Show us the whole code, it's really hard to gues what do you mean just basing on the scrap of info you gave us

Comment: Seriously could u be a little more clear on what ur problem is..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on()` and `live()` allows you to delegate any desired event handler to: current elements, or any future elements that will be added to the DOM

Use for jquery < 1.7

```
$('button').live('click', function(){

});
```

Now with .live() being deprecated in jQuery version 1.7 and removed in version 1.9, we need to use the .on() method

Use for jquery > 1.7

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the `#btn1` is created dynamically, so action handlers aren't bind to it. Use

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    alert("refresh clicked");
});
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar problem with a button in the header of the table.  At the same time I have another table that I have been using an element to clear the tables filtered data.  I couldn't figure out why one worked and the other didn't. Especially as the onEvent clearly showed that the element was being picked up and the click event should have been attached.  I think someone already said that could be because of the redraw from the scrolling.

However. I found that if I went to the parent element of the datatable and then did a find on the element that the click event did indeed stick.

Original

```
    onEvents: function ($ctrl, $tbl) {
    $('[controller=btnAttachmentAdd]', $ctrl).on('click', function () {
        alert(1);
    });
}
```

The function brings in the jquery Controller object and table object.

```
    onEvents: function ($ctrl, $tbl) {
    $ctrl.parents('.well').find('[controller=btnAttachmentAdd]').on('click', function () {
        alert(1);
    });
},
```

By moving the search area for the elements to the parent div with the class '.well' I was able to get the event to stay attached to the button.

I'm sorry if this code is a seems a little different from what the datatable on Event returns as I actually set up an object for each table I have in the database.  Then I set up different formats for the different types of lists to display.  I then call some JS object set up to act as a controller for the list that sets the columns to the desired list and attaches all events for it.

Anyway, hope the Event Attachment code helps out.